# What does (Electron) BrowserWindow's baseURLForDataURL option expect?

Tags: electron, data-uri

I'm loading a window from data-uri:

```
pref.loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(str), { baseURLForDataURL: 'file://' + app.getAppPath() } );
```

The good news is that the dev tools console shows errors now for the css/js files that should be loading but aren't, but I can't make sense of what it expects. There are no examples anywhere, not even in the github issues that inspired this option.

Does it expect an absolute path (as in my example above)?

Comment: If one hovers over the error in dev tools, it shows the full path Electron (Chrome) expects to find the file at. Compare this to what you supplied for baseURLForDataURL. In my case, app.getAppPath() gives the correct string, but the lack of a trailing slash on that path caused some hiccups somehow.

Comment: It crashes for me when I set baseURLForDataURL to 'file://'. Only relative paths compile, but then the included css/js files don't load.

Answer (score 0):

It would normally expect

```
'file://' + app.getAppPath().replace("\\", "/") + "/"
```

But at the moment, there seem to be an issue where at least when using the protocol 'file://' we get an error. (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20700)

One way of going around this issue is by generating a custom file protocol.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, screen, protocol  } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

app.on('ready', () => {
  const customProtocol = 'file2';

  protocol.registerFileProtocol(customProtocol, (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.substr(customProtocol.length + 2);
    const file = { path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`) }
    callback(file)
  });
  
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true
    }
  });
    
  win.loadURL(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${encodeURIComponent(indexHTML)}`, {
    baseURLForDataURL: `${customProtocol}://${app.getAppPath().replace("\\", "/")}/`
  });
});
```